# Using Javascript RegExp to modifiy a link

Tags: javascript, regex

I need your help and I'm a little bit lost.
So I want to obtain "https://cloud.send.cm/i/00344/zofwynu8cxc7.jpg"  from "https://send.cm/zofwynu8cxc7.html" .
As you can see "zofwynu8cxc7" is the same in both links, so basically I need to copy this photo's id to the other link. This should be possibly using regexp in js, but I'm not quite sure how. Thank you

Comment: Regex isn’t really needed for this. Use the [`URL` API](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/URL).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the `new URL("")` code:
*not sure if `path.slice()` can be done with `URL()`*

```
let url = new URL("https://send.cm/zofwynu8cxc7.html")
let path = url.pathname                                 // /zofwynu8cxc7.html
path = path.slice(0, path.length - 5)                   // /zofwynu8cxc7

console.log("https://cloud.send.cm/i/00344" + path + ".jpg")
```